# How to change workflow_data dictionary

Tags: aiogram

In the process of researching the aiogram 3 library, the question arose:

let's assume that we have a telegram bot, after creating the Dispatcher object, we added data to the workflow_data dictionary:

```
dp = Dispatcher()
dp.workflow_data.update({
         'bt': bot,
         'cfg': config,
         'test': 1
     })
```

then we start the bot with dp.start_pooling(bot)

the bot has a user called admin, his id is entered in the project's configuration file.
in the project we have the handlers package in which we have:

- admin.py - all handlers for admin, these handlers use admin_router
- user.py - - all the handlers for non-admin users, these handlers use user_router

so, in the project we have two Routers: admin_router and user_router

at the same time, in the project for each type of user (admin, user) we have the corresponding filters.

let's assume that in admin.py we have a handler for the  command:

```
@admin_router.message(Command("test"))
async def admin_test(message: Message):
    ********
```

I try in the admin_test function to change the value for the 'test' key in workflow_data as follows:

```
@admin_router.message(Command("test"))
async def admin_test(message: Message):
    admin_router.parent_router.workflow_data["test"] = 1000
    await message.answer("****")
```

the value changes only locally, within this handler.

if, however, I try to access the value for the 'test' key in workflow_data from another handler, for example in a handler from user.py

```
@user_router.message()
async def user_echo(message: Message, test):
   print(user_router.parent_router.workflow_data["test"] )
```

I get the value = 1, which means nothing has changed globally.

QUESTION: how can I globally change the value for the 'test' key in workflow_data?

can someboby help me please to solve or ..